# Работа с шаблонами документов

Tags: excel, ms-word, шаблоны-документов

Передо мной поставили такую задачу: создать **шаблон документа(doc/excel)**, а после в приложении заполнять этот шаблон данными из БД с последующей отправкой на сервис с помощью API.

Сразу в голове появился вариант с установкой на сервер с приложением Microsoft Offic'a, создание на этом сервере шаблонов Word'a/Excel'я, заполнение и отправка на сервис, но ставить Microsoft Office на сервер с приложением не хочется.

Далее я подумал о Google Docs, но проблема в том, что приложение будет использовать в Китае, а доступ к Google у них нету. Соответственно Этот вариант отпадает.

Собственно, какие еще варианты существуют?

Comment: Какой формат офиса? Если docx/xlsx - используйте OpenXML SDK.

Comment: Да, docx и xlsx.

Comment: Вы хоть на чем писать собираетесь?

Comment: Приложение на c#, asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать Visual Studio Tools For Office (VSTO). Есть возможность создавать: Надстройки (Add-Ins) и Шаблоны для MS EXCEL, MS Word. В код шаблона MS Excel добавить процесс загрузки данных из базы, например на событие: открытие книги Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл отличную библиотеку TemplateEngine.Docx, работаю с ней.

Не требуется установки Word'a на сервер, при этом быстро и просто обрабатывает документы.